# Double click on group totals

Tags: wpf, devexpress-wpf

I'm new to using WPF GridControl. I need to be able to double click on the group totals at the top and get the row and column details.
How do I achieve this please?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have you thought about creating a double click Behavior? It may be a nice way to approach the problem. Take a look here:

https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/WPF-multiclick-behavior-bb9ee00b